# How to Add jquery on Checkout page in payment method secction

Tags: magento2

I want to hide the custom section in payment method is called "Order Insurance" on checkout page as per shipping method. I mean "order insurance" will shown only for paid delivery method in case of "free delivery" it will be hide in Magento2.

Please Let me know how can I do it.

[image]